# Comparison of different active cryptocurrencies

Tags: currencies

I haven't realized until recently how many different crypto-currencies have emerged the last years; [coinmarketcap.com](http://coinmarketcap.com/) lists around 60 of them<sup>*</sup> and it seems that it isn't even a complete list (for example allahcoin that I've read about recently at HN is not listed).

I guess most of them are derived from Bitcoin and are somehow different trying to solve a real problem, eg Litecoin being more efficiently mined to reduce energy costs, but some are simply clones with only minor twists if any at all, or trying to appeal only specific audiences (gaming community, sex shoppers etc).

I think it would be interesting for me and others, a simple comparison list that explains in a few words **how the concept of each currency is different to Bitcoin and what problems are they trying to solve**, and not other details such as market capitalization, initial reward, who created it etc.

Related lists:

- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_cryptocurrencies (interesting but doesn't explain the differences of the concept)
- https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/List_of_alternative_cryptocurrencies
- https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=134179.0 (by far the most complete list and quite close to what I'm asking, but doesn't explain clearly IMHO in all items what are the differences from Bitcoin)

<sub>* Follows the list of currencies found in coinmarketcap.com that I'm interested in; description of additional active ones are of course welcome: Litecoin, MasterCoin, Peercoin, Nxt, Namecoin, Quark, ProtoShares, WorldCoin, Megacoin, Primecoin, Feathercoin, Infinitecoin, DogeCoin, Novacoin, Zetacoin, Devcoin, Anoncoin, Digitalcoin, Freicoin, Copperlark, Terracoin, Ixcoin, Cryptogenic Bullion, NetCoin, GoldCoin, Tickets, BBQCoin, StableCoin, Sexcoin, Fastcoin, Deutsche eMark, Unobtanium, MemoryCoin, Datacoin, GrandCoin, Yacoin, FlorinCoin, Mincoin, I0Coin, Tigercoin, BetaCoin, Luckycoin, TagCoin, Diamond, GlobalCoin, BitBar, CasinoCoin, EZCoin, Philosopher Stones, Phoenixcoin, Orbitcoin, Bytecoin, GameCoin, Argentum, Franko, HoboNickels, Noirbits, Joulecoin, CraftCoin, Elacoin, Junkcoin, Spots.</sub>

Comment: Please formulate the title as an actual question. There's not need for a topic that covers a general comparison between all altcoins, there are plenty of resources for that.

Comment: I think it's pretty clear what I'm asking for; if you think you can improve the title, feel free to edit the question. Actually there are not a lot of resources comparing the new altcoins to Bitcoin, if you know some, please share them to the rest of us. I believe this topic is of interest to enough users (it was for me and I had to spend time researching since there aren't good guides covering ALL the altcoins, hence the question).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You probably should start from the source by yourself, look here:

https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/network

2,523 forks of bitcoin. Greatest bump ever.

You should get source of 2 coins that you want to compare, and simply diff it. It is easiest way to understand what's the difference.

```
# git clone https://github.com/fastcoinproject/fastcoin.git 
# git clone https://github.com/asiccoin/asiccoin.git
# diff -Hrin asiccoin fastcoin
```

**92,401** different stings. The more than 70% is a `.ts` files from `/src/qt/locale/`. Only names asiccoin and fastcoin are different (:

See,

```
# rm -fr asiccoin/src/qt/locale
# rm -fr fastcoin/src/qt/locale
# diff -Hrin asiccoin fastcoin
```

**16,955** different strings.

etc.

Look, here you can get **algo**:
http://www.dustcoin.com/mining

Very good comparison list: http://www.coinwarz.com/cryptocurrency

The third one: http://coinchoose.com/

Also, check this [bitcointalk thread:  Cryptsy Survival Guide](https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=336447.msg3884343).

However, nowhere you can get full list. Forks are born every day, not only on github. There are 10-20 forks that I have meet, with hosting on google disk. 20-30 without sources.

**Edit1:** At the end, read this [thread](https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=396761.0).

**Edit2:** Look what I've found http://www.poolwarz.com